# Getting actual window width android

Tags: android

So I'm attempting to get the actual size of the phone's screen in order to center a bunch of menu buttons. On my Gingerbread phone it works fine, but on the Jellybean simulator it's all wrong...

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) Assets.context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    try{
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenHeight = size.y;
        screenWidth = size.x;
    }catch(NoSuchMethodError e){
        //API lower than 12, revert to deprecated methods
        screenWidth = display.getWidth();
        screenHeight = display.getHeight();
    }*/
```

but then when I draw, for example, a line at x = screenWidth/2, on jellybean it's nowhere near the middle of the screen! It's driving me mad, any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use `DisplayMetrics` instead. Try this:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = Assets.context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
int heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Display display =getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

try{

    screenHeight = display.getHeight();;
    screenWidth = display.getWidth();
}catch(NoSuchMethodError e){
    //API lower than 12, revert to deprecated methods

}*/
```